# Connecting to Wscat and having authorization error

Tags: alpaca, wscat

I used this to connect:
`wscat --connect wss://api.alpaca.markets/stream`
then used
`{"action": "auth", "key": "key", "secret": "key"}`
and got this error:
`{"stream":"authorization","data":{"action":"auth","message":"access key verification failed","status":"unauthorized"}}`

I just set this account up so not sure what I need to do with authentication. This is on alpaca too btw.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your data stream URLs: https://alpaca.markets/docs/api-references/market-data-api/stock-pricing-data/realtime/
- Regenerate your API keys (required after resetting a paper account)